# Trend Dampen with SARIMA

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality, statsmodels, exponential-smoothing

Trend dampen exists as a parameter for Holt-Winters in the `ExponentialSmoothing` class for `statsmodels` but how can I do something like this with a SARIMA model in `statsmodels`?  Essentially allow the seasonality to remain the same but bring down the trend in the long run.